# Html Javascript Firebase Creating User

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to create a `user` in `firebase` for my `website` using `javascript` and `HTML` like this:

My `HTML` code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.13.0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config =
      {
        apiKey: "myKey",
        authDomain: "myDomain",
        databaseURL: "myDatabaseUrl",
        projectId: "myProjectId",
        storageBucket: "myStorageBucket",
        messagingSenderId: "myMessagingSenderId"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);
    </script>

    <script src = "signUpScript.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <input type="button" value="SignUp" onclick = "signUpButton_TouchUpInside()">
  </body>
```

And this is my `javascript`:

```
function signUpButton_TouchUpInside()
{

  var userEmail = document.getElementById("emailTextFieldSignUp").value;
  var userPassword = document.getElementById("passwordTextFieldSignUp").value;
  var userName = document.getElementById("nameTextFieldSignUp").value;

  window.alert("test1"); // does get called

  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword).catch(function(error)
  {
    window.alert("test2"); // doesnt get called
    if (error)
    {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      window.alert("There went something wrong : " + errorMessage);
      // ...
    }
    else
    {
      window.alert("test3"); // doesnt get called
      setUserInfo("", "", userName, userEmail, "1"); // How do I get the uid of the user which was just created?
    }
  });
}

function setUserInfo(profileImageUrl, profileBannerUrl, username, email, uid)
{
  var userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
  var ref = firebase.database().ref();
  var userRef = ref.child("users").child(userId);

  userRef.set({
    username: username,
    username_lowercase: username.toLowerCase().replace(" ", ""),
    email: email,
    profileImageUrl: profileImageUrl,
    profileBannerUrl: profileBannerUrl
  }, function(error)
  {
    if (error)
    {
      var errorMessage = error.message;

      window.alert("There went something wrong : " + errorMessage);
    }
    else
    {
      window.alert("Account successfully created");
    }
  });
}
```

For some reason, it doesn't even call the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` function.

So I've got two questions:

1. Why doesn't the function get called?
2. If it did get called how would I access the `uid` of the just created  user?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I honestly don't even know what that is. I'm pretty new, I'm sorry

Comment: None of the code you shared calls `signUpButton_TouchUpInside`, so that would explain it if `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` isn't called. Did you wire it up in the HTML somewhere? If so, share the minimal HTML for that too. In general, have a look at [how to create a minimal complete verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). As that it the best way to improve the chances that someone here can help.

Comment: Alright, I edited my question. I now added my HTML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current code only catches errors from `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`. The reason most example only use `catch` is that it's typically best to handle the "account creation successful" flow in an `onAuthStateChanged` handler.

The smallest change from your current code is that add a `then()`:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, userPassword)
  .then(function(user) {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    setUserInfo("", "", userName, userEmail, user.uid)
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    // no `if (error)` is needed here: if `catch` is called, there was an error
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;

    window.alert("There went something wrong : " + errorMessage);
  });
```

The better change though, as said, is to [use an `onAuthStateChanged`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed_in_user), which then automatically also ensures your user info is updated whenever the user reloads the app:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in, call setUserInfo here
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Comment: Ok, thank you-you really helped me with that. But now it, fortunately, does add the user to the `Authentication`, but unfortunately,  not to the database. Did I do something wrong there as well?

Comment: I've rephrased my question

Comment: That sounds like a new problem. Please don't change your question after a solution for the current question has been given, but open a new question for the new problem. That allows others to help too. Also: don't forget to upvote and/or accept my answer.